# How to test that views are overlapping?

Tags: android, android-espresso, ui-testing

Using espresso, how to test that views are overlapping?

`isDisplayed()` will return true, even though it's not visible to the user.

`isCompletelyVisible()` is used for scrollable views.

`noOverlaps` only deals with `TextView` and `ImageView`.

Views are created on the fly, and don't have any id assigned. It also doesn't matter if they are completely or partially overlapping.

I'm thinking to compare the index of 2 views inside the parent container?

Comment: Will you be able to get the position and measured width/ height of the Views? (sorry, not familiar with espresso)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could you use a combination of the PositionAssertions mentioned here:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/assertion/PositionAssertions

maybe a combination of `isCompletelyAbove() || isCompletelyBelow() || is CompletelyLeftOf() || isCompletelyRightOf()` could get you what you want?

Or the opposite `isPartiallyAbove() || isPartiallyBelow() || isPartiallyLeftOf() || isPartiallyRightOf()`?

Or you could create your own ViewAssertion that checks the on screen position and width/height of each view and compare that way?